# Null ServerSession on CometD /meta/handshake

Tags: cometd

Section [6.3.6.4](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/concepts_low_level.html#concepts_message_processing) and the bottom of section [7.2](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/javascript_handshake.html) of the CometD documentation discuss how to establish a Listener on the /meta/handshake channel to map user IDs to ServerSessions/ServerSession IDs for use in private messaging. However, when listening on the /meta/handshake channel, the ServerSession received is null, so there is no way to create the map. Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

My assumption at this point is that the HandshakeHandler Listener (added to the /meta/handshake channel in the initializeMetaChannels method of BayeuxServerImpl.java) is getting invoked after or at the same time as the custom Listener that I have created on the same channel. Since the HandshakeHandler is what actually creates the ServerSession, this results in my custom Listener receiving a null ServerSession. This is supported by the fact that the BayeuxServer SecurityPolicy's canHandshake method, which gets invoked by the HandshakeHandler after it creates the ServerSession, is getting invoked *after* my custom listener. I presume that the CometD documentation stating that a ServerSession to UserID map can be constructed from within a /meta/handshake Listener is in error.

Comment: Which CometD version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated analysis is correct.
The documentation should be updated, since the first point where the session will be available is in `SecurityPolicy.canHandshake()`.
I tracked this issue with http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-522.

Comment: It would be preferable if there was a way to construct a user ID / ServerSession map without coupling it to the SecurityPolicy. A BayeuxServer.SessionListener provides the ServerSession, but it doesn't provide the ServerMessage so that's not an option. Obviously you wouldn't want to do this on the /meta/connect channel either because the polling would force repeated checks to see if the userId is already in the map. Thoughts on an alternative approach?

Comment: I don't understand why you consider implementing an interface called `SecurityPolicy` "coupling" while implementing an interface called `ServerChannel.MessageListener` or `BayeuxServer.SessionListener` is not coupling ?  A

Comment: The suggestion to have the ServerMessage available in the `SessionListener` is sound, though, and may be implemented in CometD 3 (http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-523). The `SecurityPolicy` is the way to go, see for example also: http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/howtos/authentication

Comment: My thinking here is that a `SecurityPolicy` should be managing things directly related to security. As such, it seems that logic for constructing a map of userIds and `ServerSession`s needed to enable private message delivery does not belong in the implementation of a `SecurityPolicy`. In contrast, a `Listener` is a more generic construct intended for a variety of purposes.